# Is it possible to put this shape with a white border and transparent background?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to put this shape transparent inside, with a white border. The problem is that i don't know how to change the right side of the shape. I would like to do the same thing that i did on the left side.

How can i do that? Thanks.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/2pz0kLd4/

Code:

```
.arrow-steps {
  width: 128px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top:1px solid white;
  border-left:1px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-top:30px;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.arrow-steps:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;

}
.arrow-steps:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid red;

}

.arrow-steps a{
display:block;
margin-top:36px;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Here's a [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/3uxqa6zs/1/)

```
body{
background-color:black;
}

.arrow-steps {
  width: 128px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top:1px solid white;
  border-left:1px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
  margin-right:30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top:30px;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.arrow-steps:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 12px solid red; 
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.arrow-steps:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
  border-left: 12px solid red; 
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.arrow-steps a{
  display:block;
  margin-top:36px;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic solution to allow both sides to have a border (would need to be altered as I haven't made it responsive)

```css
html {
  background: tomato;
}
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 42px;
  top: 8px;
  left: -22px;
  width: 42px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  perspective: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 42px;
  top: 8px;
  right: -22px;
  width: 42px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  perspective: 100px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div>SOME TEXT</div>
```